# Do the laws of mathematics apply in Australia?

Tags: australia, evidence

According to Malcolm Turnbull, Prime Minister of Australia ["The laws of mathematics are very commendable, but the only law that applies in Australia is the law of Australia"](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/2017/07/14/malcolm-turnbull-says-laws-australia-trump-laws-mathematics/). My question is, is this true?

For example, in the US, [Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law), a law of mathematics, [can be used as evidence in a court of law](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/2017/07/14/malcolm-turnbull-says-laws-australia-trump-laws-mathematics/). More examples of laws of mathematics being used in court can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1021519).

My question is then, can the laws of mathematics be used in Australia? For example, could Benford's law be used in Australian court, or would be thrown out, seeing as the only law that applies in Australia is the law of Australia? What about other sciences?

Comment: This question seems to be more about the semantics and the meaning of words rather than any sort of legal question. If so then it is not appropriate and so Ive voted to close.

Comment: Is this a tongue-in-cheek question, or do you really not understand the differences between those two different meanings of the word "law?"

Comment: @feetwet I'm using the word law in two different senses in this question (legislation v.s. evidence). It's the prime who conflated the two.

Comment: The Prime Minister seems to be taking some obvious rhetorical liberties to produce a good "pull-quote."  And you seem to be either taking his bait or baiting readers here with the same.  I just glanced at the article and don't see anything of substance that raises the question you have asked.

Answer (score 2):

A law - generally -  is a piece of legislation passed by a state, or in common law systems, may also be the principles that are stated within decisions by courts.

Your question seems to interpret a "law" of mathematics as a law in the legal sense. However,  despite the word "law" being used in both contexts, they refer to different things.

A law in maths (if there are such things)  refers to some sort of logical "truth" that is immutable if certain axioms are followed.

We are clearly not talking about the same kind of "law".

Sure,  mathematic principles may be brought up in the evidence of an expert witness, say with regards to the mathematical likelihood of an event happening.

But rest assured such evidence is not law.

Law isn't something you bring to court as evidence.

Comment: So would Benford's law, or other mathematical laws, count as evidence then, or wouldn't they apply in Australia?

Comment: Are you asking what the penalty is for breaking Benford's law? You don't get full marks in the test.

Answer (score 0):

A law is a rule, whether physical, mathematical or legal, that states a regular relationship (between things, numbers, or people). In law, "If you speed you will be fined" is one such relationship. A physical or mathematical law would be admissible only if it it relevant, for example when combined with observational evidence to establish that the accused could not have committed the act. Such laws can't be just introduced willy-nilly: they have to have probative value.